# Undefined Reference Error When Compiling Wont go Away?

Tags: c

I am working on a proxy lab for class and don't understand why when i try to compile my solution using make, it gives me  `` "undefined reference to `sem_init'" ``,  `` undefined reference to `Pthread_create' ``...etc. It does this on at least 12 or 15 of my functions. The problem is, it says that the issue is in the csapp.c file, but i can only modify and hand in the proxy.c file. I am compiling it using -lpthread and i have read a lot of people have gotten rid of these undefined errors because they werent using that. So i don't know why i am still getting these issues when i am using the -lpthread flag.

Does anyone have any other things that i may be missing as to why i am getting these undefined reference errors? Thanks

This is my make file:

```
TEAM = NOBODY
VERSION = 1
HANDINDIR = /afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f02/L7/handin

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = -lpthread

OBJS = proxy.o csapp.o

all: proxy

proxy: $(OBJS)

csapp.o: csapp.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c csapp.c

proxy.o: proxy.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c proxy.c

handin:
    cp proxy.c $(HANDINDIR)/$(TEAM)-$(VERSION)-proxy.c

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o proxy core
```

Here is just some of the proxy.c file:

```
#include "csapp.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "pthread.h"
#include "stdio.h"

//Global variables
sem_t mutex;
sem_t log_mutex;

/*
 * Function prototypes
 */
int parse_uri(char *uri, char *target_addr, char *path, int  *port);
void format_log_entry(char *logstring, struct sockaddr_in *sockaddr, char *uri, int size);
void log_to_file(char * log_entry);
//void handle_request(int *fd);



//WRAPPERS
//Wrapper for rio_readnb that doesn't exit the program
ssize_t Rio_readnb_w(rio_t *rp, void *usrbuf, size_t n)
{
    ssize_t rc;
    if ((rc = rio_readnb(rp, usrbuf, n)) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Rio_readnb failed!\n");
        return rc;
    }
    return rc;
}

//Wrapper for rio_readlineb that doesn't exit the program
ssize_t Rio_readlineb_w(rio_t *rp, void *usrbuf, size_t maxlen)
{
    ssize_t rc;
    if ((rc = rio_readlineb(rp, usrbuf, maxlen)) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Rio_readlineb failed!\n");
        return rc;
    }
    return rc;
}

//Wrapper for rio_writen that doesn't exit the program
void Rio_writen_w(int fd, void *usrbuf, size_t n)
{
    if (rio_writen(fd, usrbuf, n) != n)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Rio_writen failed!\n");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've not shown any code, have you included the appropriate header files?

Comment: You should include some code that causes this error, and the full output from running `make`...

Comment: Posting uncompilable fragments of code isn't all that productive. Do an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using GNU make.

You didn't specify any link rule in your makefile, and the [implicit link rule](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html) is:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

where `n.o` is your object files.  Further; the GNU linker requres that library names come after the object files that are supposed to link against those libraries, so if you change your `LDFLAGS` to `LDLIBS` then it may fix your problem.

It'd be useful if you post the actual link command that your makefile attempts to execute (so we can verify that this implicit rule is being used). Of course you could write your own link rule instead of relying on the implicit rule.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which line to change or add in my makefile that i posted above. The file was supposidly supposed to be correct from the instructor but something isn't right!

Comment: "GNU linker requres that library names come after the object files that are supposed to link against those libraries". Experiments show that this doesn't really matter for shared libraries.

Comment: @user3704961 post the complete output of when you run `make`

Comment: @@user3704961 also try changing `LDFLAGS` to `LDLIBS` (may or may not fix the problem)